# Azure Table Storage upgrade

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I have an Azure Table Storage with the following Entity:

```
SampleEntity : TableEntity
{
  public int EmployeeId{get; set;}
}
```

And I have inserted 100 records to the table.
Now I have a change in requirement that the EmployeeID should be string. Also I should not delete the existing 100 records that were inserted.
Hence I changed the existing SampleEntity as follows:

```
SampleEntity : TableEntity
{
  public string EmployeeId{get; set;}
}
```

And I have inserted 50 Rows into the table with EmployeeId as string.

Now when I do a GetOperation on the table with new SampleEntity(with string EmployeeID), I am getting 150 rows, but the values of EmployeeID for the first 100 rows inserted using the Old SampleEntity was
0.

On  the other hand if I switch to old SampleEntity and do a GetOperaiton, I get null values for EmployeeID for the 50 rows inserted using new SampleEntity.

How can I use the new Sample Entity toget all 150 rows with values for EmployeeId in Strings?

Comment: Why mysql, sql, sql-server tags?

Comment: Will you be OK with changing the `integer` EmployeeId to `string` EmployeeId (without deleting them of course) or do you want to preserve the data types?

Comment: @GauravMantri: I do not want to preserve data types.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you could possibly do is change the data type of `Integer` type EmployeeId to `String`. For this what you would need to do is fetch all entities as `DynamicTableEntity` and check the property type of `EmployeeId` property. If the type is `Int32`, you would create a new entity with a `String` type `EmployeeId` property and set its value to old entity's `EmployeeId` value and then update the existing entity (you will keep the same `PartitionKey` and `RowKey`).

See the sample code below for example:

```
        //Get all entities and make sure we get them as dynamic table entity.
        var query = new TableQuery();
        var allEntities = table.ExecuteQuery(query);
        foreach (var entity in allEntities)
        {
            var propertyType = entity.Properties["EmployeeId"].PropertyType;
            if (propertyType == EdmType.Int32 && entity.Properties["EmployeeId"].Int32Value.HasValue)
            {
                //This is an entity with Integer type EmployeeId. What we need to do is update this entity with a new entity where data type of EmployeeId is String.
                var employeeId = entity.Properties["EmployeeId"].Int32Value.Value;
                var newEntityWithStringType = new DynamicTableEntity()
                {
                    PartitionKey = entity.PartitionKey,
                    RowKey = entity.RowKey,
                    ETag = "*"
                };
                newEntityWithStringType.Properties.Add("EmployeeId", new EntityProperty(employeeId.ToString()));
                TableOperation updateOperation = TableOperation.Replace(newEntityWithStringType);
                table.Execute(updateOperation);
            }
        }
```

The code above assumes that you only have one property `EmployeeId`. If there are more properties, please make sure to include them in `newEntityWithStringType` Properties.

Comment: This solution has multiple issues: 1) It can't scale to more than a few hundred rows without costing a lot. 2) A basic feature of most NoSQL systems (including Azure Tables) is that the schema can change without affecting older entries. It's the *application* that has to deal with it. Your solution negates this

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos I agree. This is just a sample code to show how can one change the data type. Also, from the comments from Rockstart, they changed the underlying model and thus wanted to convert data type at the storage level itself. I think it boils down to your application requirement. If you want to deal with schema changes at the application level, then I guess you will have to go with DynamicTableEntity approach and do the serializtion yourself. However if you wish to keep just one model, then I guess you would need to convert the data in storage.

Comment: The point is that you *shouldn't* try to change the data type at all but handle the different schemas. It's not a matter of application requirements but using a system properly or not. Remember, table transactions (both read and write) cost. Updating each time you want to modify the schema quickly becomes very expensive.

Comment: I kind of disagree. Agreed that we have the flexibility of having no schema at all but in the end it all depends on what your application requirements are. In one of my project, we're taking full advantage of schemaless nature of table storage to store similar kind of entities and it works beautifully. In the same project, we had some design changes and had to change our model. There we ended up changing entity's data type. The cost of changing the data one time was much cheaper than keeping it dynamic and handling that in the application always.

Comment: I've seen multiple examples suggesting using `entity.Properties["propertyName"].WhatEver`. However, `Properties` attribute is not found while trying to replicate this. My `entity` inherits from `ITableEntity` which does not have it. Any idea what it could be?